# How to create a pole to follow and empty with arbitrary origin

Tags: constraints, tracking, origin

I want my "pole" follow point B from point A with no stretching, this way

[image]

Intead of this I get this:

[image]

How can I follow the point B using the pole, keeping the point A as origin, and keeping the movement as you can see in the empty C
[image]

Comment: If by "follow" you mean that the pole tip at B stays at B and the pole tip at A stays at A, then i suggest an approach with armatures. You Would need 3 Bones one from C to A one from A to B and one from the Origin to point B. (Then with some constraints of the rotation direction, Copy translation constraints for staing at Origin and point C and an IK-constraint between the first and the second bone...) You could then parent your visual objects to those bones.

Comment: so I guess your object will rotate a bit around the A axis, otherwise I don't know how it can follow B

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that's what you want because it's not clear to me but I give a try with this:

Create Bone1 and his child Bone2. Create Bone3 and his child Bone4. Give Bone2 an *IK Constraint* with Bone4 as *Target*. Now Bone2 sticks to Bone4.

For the rotation of Bone3: In the 3D View right panel (displayed with <kbd>N</kbd>), choose *XYZ Euler* instead of *Quaternion*. Create a keyframe at angle 0°, rotate the bone 180° and create a second keyframe, then in the Dopesheet press T > *Linear* and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *Linear Extrapolation* to make the rotation perpetual.

[image]